# Excel gives incorrect Paste error instead of "out of range" error in Compatibility Mode

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am an experienced Excel user. This error was bewildering.

Using Excel in Office 365.

I didn't realize I was in Compatibility Mode and only had 65536 rows to work with. I routinely work with spreadsheets that are much larger.

I was trying to paste 22581 rows of data into a sheet that already had 46076 rows of data. Instead of telling me that my paste data didn't fit because there weren't enough rows in the sheet, Excel unhelpfully suggested I try just selecting one cell in the target sheet.

[image]

Error text:

> You can't paste this here because the Copy area and paste area aren't
>   the same size.
>
> Select just one cell in the paste area or an area that's the same
>   size, and try pasting again.

Is this error message a bug?